# Is it a good idea to use accent characters in Firebase realtime database keys?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, utf-8, diacritics

I would like to use accent characters in my Firebase realtime database keys because it would result a simpler database structure for my web app. Is it safe to use or should I convert accent characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database are Unicode strings, so can use any valid Unicode characters except for these characters listed in the documentation:

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain `.`, `$`, `#`, `[`, `]`, `/`, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the values themselves, either.

Whether you like using non-ASCII characters in keys is a personal preference, but not a limitation of the database. There is no right or wrong here.

I have many nodes where I just use push (or otherwise auto-generated) keys with a limited dictionary. But I also regularly have keys where I store actual user-entered values, such as a node where the child keys are user names so that we can ensure they are unique.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use accent characters in keys then.